# Cannot export service angular library

Tags: html, angular, service

Hi i am trying to export a service from my library but i am always getting an error.
this is my module where i import the service:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from 'ecarelib/lib/services/app-config.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [AppConfigService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Public-api:

```
export * from './lib/services/app-config.service';
```

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ecarelib/lib/services/app-config.service' in 'C:\Users\ArneVandenEynden\vitalsigns\Ecare.VitalSigns.Client\src\app'

Comment: what is the exact path of your service from src folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the import path for '**AppConfigService**' provided in **AppModule** is incorrect. You should give the relative path there.

For example:

If the **AppConfigService**'s path is **src>ecarelib>lib>services>app-config.service** and **AppModule**'s path is **src>app>app.module**, then the import path that we should provide is the relative path as shown below:

```
import { AppConfigService } from '../ecarelib/lib/services/app-config.service';
```

Instead of :

```
import { AppConfigService } from 'ecarelib/lib/services/app-config.service';
```

Hope this would resolve the issue.